# Overwrite a default argument with another one using the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

can anyone help me to overwrite a default argument with another one passing through the command line ?
this is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('log', action='store', help='path to the log file')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filter', default =['filter.json'], help='path to a filter file')
parser.add_argument('-w', '--waiver', type =list, default = [], action='append', help='path to a waiver file')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

this is the command line to be used:

```
python3 script.py -f filter_file -w waiver_file log_file
```

so, I need to overwrite this `default =['filter.json']` with filter_file

But don't know what should I do, can you support please ?

thanks

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown? It looks like it could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working:
My output:

PS C:\Users\xf01145\Documents\Python> & "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe"

```
c:/Users/xf01145/Documents/Python/cli.py log.log -f bla.bla blubb.bla test.test hugo.txt
Namespace(filter=['bla.bla', 'blubb.bla', 'test.test', 'hugo.txt'], log='log.log', waiver=[])
0 bla.bla
1 blubb.bla
2 test.test
3 hugo.txt
PS C:\Users\xf01145\Documents\Python>
```

from this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('log', action='store', help='path to the log file')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--filter', default =['filter.json'], help='path to a filter file',  nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-w', '--waiver', type =list, default = [], action='append', help='path to a waiver file')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)

for i,item in enumerate(args.filter):
    print(i, item)
```

Comment: Seems working, but i am still facing an issue while trying to do something like: for element in filters (elements of filter list) do something with, it take that list as a string  returning this error "no such file or directory f " so f is the first letter in filter_file name

Comment: Do you have one filter file, or do you want do add one or more files?

Comment: Want to have the possibility to add more

Comment: I edited my solution post. Hopefully this is what you want.

Comment: yes, but the default filter_file still not overwritten

Comment: It is, there is no filter.json in the output. See output above

Comment: is there any action like : action='append'  to overwrite to default element of the list like doing action='update' ?

Comment: Please show me, what you want to see and how you start the script with its parameters

Comment: Nice, then please accept the answer if it helped you out.